# c_str вылетает ошибка

Tags: типы-данных, c++

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    OpenFileDialog ^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

    if (openFileDialog1 -> ShowDialog() ==::System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK ) {
        FILE * fr = fopen(openFileDialog1 -> FileName.c_str(), "r");
        if (NULL == fr) {
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Ошибка при открытии файла");
        }
        fclose(fr);
    }
}
```

пытаюсь открыть файл но вылетает ошибка в строке `FILE *fr = fopen(openFileDialog1->FileName.c_str(),"r");`

`error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union`
в чём тут дело? насколько я понимаю я правильно перевожу тип или есть в чём-то подвох?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса System::String нет метода c_str(), это метод класса std::string. Можно попробовать конвертировать в std::string:

std::string ToCppString(System::String * str) { if (str == 0) { return(std::string()); }
System::IntPtr ptr(System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Str ingToHGlobalAnsi(str));

std::string ret(static_cast<const char *>(static_cast<void* >(ptr)));

System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::FreeCoT askMem(ptr);
return(ret);

}

взял с http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/280555-convert-system-string-char

Либо, что на мой взгляд будет более правильно, использовать методы работы с файлами предоставляемые .Net Framework (раз Вы все равно уже используете его).

Так у класса OpenFileDialog есть метод OpenFile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile.aspx) для открытия файла только для чтения, если вам нужно записать, то можно воспользоваться SaveFileDialog, его метод метод открывает файл на чтение и запись (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.openfile.aspx). Примеры использованиея есть на msdn по приведенным ссылкам.

Comment: хорошо это меня устраивает(метод openfile), но не пойму как поток stream загнать в переменную